# insert query in sqlite using corona?

Tags: sqlite, coronasdk

How to insert a string like this:

```
 local Namestring="my mother's gift"

local insertQuery1 =[[INSERT INTO planne_tbl VALUES (']]..Namestring..[[');]]

db:exec( insertQuery1 )
```

How to insert `'` symbol in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing SQL commands by concatenating strings will not only lead to formatting problems but will also allow [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

The recommended way to use string values in SQL is to use parameters.
In Lua, it works like this:

```lua
local Namestring="my mother's gift"
local insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO planne_tbl VALUES (?)"
local stmt = db:prepare(insertQuery1)
stmt:bind(1, Namestring)
stmt:step()
stmt:finalize()
```

(This is needlessly complex; you might want to write a helper function for this.)

Comment: Do we need to do the same for a select with a variable such as : local displayitems = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE code='"..itemcode.."' and area='"..vararea.."'"

Comment: These strings could contain quotes, too.